# How to update help for specific cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, cmd

how to update help for cmdlets? for example I need to update help only for New-Item?

Comment: You can't - it's on a per-module basis - so you'd have to do `Update-Help -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's documentation on Update-Help you cannot update the help for a specific cmdlet.  Only the module the cmdlet belongs to can have all its' documentation updated.  The documentation outlines a two step process

1. Find out the module it belongs to with:
   (Get-Command ).ModuleName
2. Update the help for the modules with:
   Update-Help -Module

I prefer using the oneliner:
$module = $(Get-Command ).Module ; Update-Help -Module $module

Since $Get-Command does not support the -Passthru flag you have to store the first command's result into an object then pass that object as a parameter to Update-Help

For more information look at the information from running either
get-help update-help
get-help update-help -Examples | more

You can also view Microsoft's online documentation at  information online athttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_updatable_help?view=powershell-7.1
IF the link is dead search for docs for update-help